# How to send outlook email automatically using Excel UserForm?

Tags: vba, email, outlook, sendkeys

Thanks for any help with this. I have a userform I've made that gathers criteria from the user and then when they hit submit it opens Outlook and emails that data to me.

I'm having 2 issues. The first is that when I try to use SENDKEYS method I'm running into the spell check feature stopping the email from actually sending without the user needing to go through it. Is there a way to bypass spell check and send the email?

Secondly, I couldn't find a way to actual send an email automatically without using SENDKEYS but I'm sure there is a better way out there to send the email rather than manipulating the window with TAB key strokes.

```
Private Sub SubmitButton_Click()
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim strBody, RequestName, ProductName, Month, TestName, Summary As String

If Me.RequesterNameTxt.Value <> "" And Me.ProductCombo.Value <> "" And Me.MonthCombo.Value <> "" And Me.TestNameCombo <> "" Then
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

RequestName = Me.RequesterNameTxt.Value
ProductName = Me.ProductCombo.Value
Month = Me.MonthCombo.Value
TestName = Me.TestNameCombo.Value
Summary = Me.SummaryTxt.Value


strBody = "<HTML><BODY>"
strBody = "Requester Name: " & RequestName & "<BR>" & "Product Name: " & ProductName & "<BR>" & "Month: " & Month & "<BR>" & _
"Test Name: " & TestName & "<BR>" & "<BR>" & "Summary of Request: " & Summary
strBody = strBody & "</BODY></HTML>"

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = "example@gmail.com;"
    .CC = ""
    .bcc = ""
    .Subject = "QA Service Request"
    .htmlBody = strBody
    .send 'This fixed my issue. I had this as .Display which opens email up and doesn't send
End With
On Error GoTo 0
Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
Application.SendKeys ("%s")
    Else: MsgBox "Please fill out all form data before submitting request. Thank you!"
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: hello, please check Ron de Bruin's website which is really useful, ı am pretty sure you can find everything you are looking for about sending mail with excel  [LINK](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/mail.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [Send](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866779(v=office.15).aspx) method of Outlook items instead. The Send method sends an item using the default account specified for the session. In a session where multiple Microsoft Exchange accounts are defined in the profile, the first Exchange account added to the profile is the primary Exchange account, and is also the default account for the session. To specify a different account to send an item, set the [SendUsingAccount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869311.aspx) property to the desired [Account](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869974.aspx) object and then call the Send method.

Also I'd recommend using the Recipients property for adding recipients instead. The property returns a Recipients collection that represents all the recipients for the Outlook item.